# Adding value to database

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, jdbc

I use mysql workbench and netbeans 
I have a table in mysql: Products that contains productsquantity=50 for example

in java, I want to add a value from text field to the database ( 50+value to add) please help, I use this code and didn't work

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/joebdd";

String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

String user = "root";

String pass = "12345";


//Error is here:
String sql = "UPDATE Produit " + "  SET Quantity =
Quantity+'"+Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText())+"' " + "WHERE ProductName = ? " ;





try

{

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();


    Connection conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, jTextField4.getText());

    pst.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());

pst.executeUpdate();}

catch( Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of the single quotes around the quantity that you're adding would fix your problem.

A better solution would be to use a `?` in place of that quantity, and set it with `setInt`.  So the SQL would be

```
UPDATE Produit SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE ProductName = ?
```

and the line to set it would be

```
pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()));
```

Comment: i used   :String sql = "UPDATE Produit " + "  SET Quantity = ? +'"+Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText())+"' " + "WHERE ProductName = ? " ; and it works             thxx a lot

Comment: No it doesn't.  Have a look at what the quantity is getting set to.